# Should i change the automatic transmission oil cooler for my BMW F30?

Tags: bmw

I’m not sure whether i should be changing the Automatic Transmission Oil Cooler as a preventive maintenance for my BMW F30 2014 with 188,000km mileage.

The part is found here https://www.bimmerworld.com/Cooling/Oil-Coolers/Automatic-Transmission-Oil-Cooler-BMW-F22-F30-F32-17217600553.html

I live in Egypt, and the dealership usually change it at 120,000km as a form of preventive maintenance. So far i don’t have any problems so i’m not sure whether i should be changing it. Is this usual in other countries?

Comment: It's unclear from your post: Did your dealer change it at 120k? If so, you shouldn't worry about it. If not, then you should probably get it done if it is recommended.

Comment: i don’t do the maintenance at the dealership, but i heard the dealership changes the cooler at 120km, so was checking if this is necessary